# Remembering Google Two Factor authentication while clearning cookies

Tags: cookies, google-account, two-factor-authentication

I have enable 2-Factor authentication on google. I want to clear all the cookies in my browser (firefox/iceweasel) at the end of the session while retaining the "remember for 30 days" feature. I've tried rules for retaining specific cookies from accounts.google.com, google.com, google.co.in, etc, but it appears that either I stay logged in, or I have to log in with the second factor.

So the question is:
1. Is the "remember.." feature working only via cookies?
2. Are the cookies allowing login separate from those allowing second factor authentication? If yes, which cookies do I retain?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on SuperUser, bottom line is: keep all Google Cookies or enter authentication code every time.

https://superuser.com/questions/702976/which-cookie-is-the-googles-two-factor-authentication-related-cookie